# SUM con inner join mysql

Tags: mysql

Quiero mostrar información de cada proveedor hacer una suma de cuantos ingresos tuvo en una fecha determinada.

```
Mi tabla entrada
-----------------------
cajas  peso idproveedor
-----------------------
100    1000      1
100    2000      1


Tabla proveedor
-----------------------
id  nombre
-----------------------
1   Manuel Morales
```

estaba haciendolo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
COALESCE(SUM(cajas),0) as total_cajas, 
COALESCE(SUM(peso),0) as total_peso
FROM entrada INNER JOIN entrada.idproveedor = proveedor.id
```

pero me marca error. ¿Como podria hacer para que salga el siguiente resultado?

```
---------------------------------------------------------
idproveedor   nombre_proveedor  total_cajas   total_peso
---------------------------------------------------------
    1         Manuel Morales     200           3000
```

y así sucesivamente con cada proveedor

Comment: Cual es el error que te marca

Comment: es un error de sintaxis, lo puse como ejemplo pero realmente no esta bien la consulta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer asi:

```
SELECT proveedor.id, proveedor.nombre,
COALESCE(SUM(cajas),0) as total_cajas, 
COALESCE(SUM(peso),0) as total_peso
FROM entrada INNER JOIN proveedor ON entrada.idproveedor = proveedor.id
GROUP BY entrada.idproveedor
```

Comment: ok, me muestra lo que ha producido cada proveedor mas no me muestra el nombre de proveedor ni su id, como adjunto eso?

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo que lo recomendable en este caso es hacer uso de Group By (MySQL).

```
CREATE TABLE PROVEEDOR(
  ID int NOT NULL,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE ENTRADA(
  ID int NOT NULL,
  CAJAS INT,
  PESO INT,
  ID_PROVEEDOR INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (ID_PROVEEDOR) REFERENCES PROVEEDOR(ID)
);

INSERT INTO PROVEEDOR(ID,NOMBRE) VALUES(1,'Manuel Morales');
INSERT INTO ENTRADA(ID,CAJAS,PESO,ID_PROVEEDOR) VALUES(1,100,1000,1);
INSERT INTO ENTRADA(ID,CAJAS,PESO,ID_PROVEEDOR) VALUES(2,100,2000,1);

SELECT P.ID AS ID_PROVEEDOR, 
  P.NOMBRE AS NOMBRE_PROVEEDOR, 
  SUM(E.CAJAS) AS TOTAL_CAJAS,
  SUM(E.PESO) AS TOTAL_PESO
    FROM ENTRADA AS E
    INNER JOIN PROVEEDOR AS P
    ON E.ID_PROVEEDOR = P.ID
    GROUP BY(P.ID)
```

Te dejo el enlace de SQLFiddle para que puedas jugar con la consulta 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f41acc/3

Saludos.

Comment: se repiten datos con el mismo proveedor https://imgur.com/m02lnC5

Comment: Verifica si en tu tabla proveedores hay nombres repetidos, además verifica si hay id repetidos.

Comment: Si en tu tabla no existen ID repetidos el Group By se debe hacer con el ID.